# Getting a cookie from a WebClient POST request?

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies, asp.net-web-api, webclient

I'm trying to send a POST request to an API controller that sets an authentication cookie.  I need to retrieve that cookie, but I'm not sure how.  What I have:

Sending, from a service:

```
  public static Cookie Authenticate(string username, string url) {
        using (var client = new WebClient()) {
            client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            var data = "="+username;
            var test = client.UploadString(url, "POST", data);
            // get cookie here, converted from HttpCookie
            return new Cookie();
        }
    }
```

Receiving, on API Controller:

```
    [Route("api/auth")]
    [System.Web.Http.AcceptVerbs("POST")]
    public HttpCookie SetCookie([FromBody] string username) {
        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username, true);
        return FormsAuthentication.GetAuthCookie(decrypted, true);
    }
```

Currently, this returns what I believe is a string representation of the cookie, which doesn't do me much good.  How can I capture the HttpCookie from the WebClient?

Comment: `client.Headers[HttpResponseHeader.SetCookie]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WebClient` is a high level abstraction that doesn't expose cookies to the consumer.

You have two options:

You can derive your own class from WebClient, override the `GetWebResponse` method and read the cookies at that point

Or you can just use lower level classes like `HttpWebRequest` directly.